# Executing Ember.Handlebars templates without using Ember.View

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, ember.js, handlebars.js

I am using RoR with the ember-rails gem on the server side and Ember.js on the client side.
The on the server side located (Handlebars-)templates are delivered in the Ember.TEMPLATES variable on the client side.
These templates can be used within an Ember.View.

All of this works like a charm, but now the problem:

I have a very small piece of html i want to render.
It is, from my point of view, not worth to create a Ember.View for that.
So what i would like to do something like that..

```
Ember.TEMPLATES.name_of_the_template(
    {
        my_text_variable : "my_text"
    }
);
```

This raises an error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'buffer' of undefined

I've looked up the code and i know why this happens (the templates can only be used within a Ember.View or maybe other Ember-Objects).

With Handlebars it is working, but there i have no access to the on the server side stored Handlebars-Templates..

Someone has any suggestions how i can solve this?

Please let me know if you need more information!

Thx!

Comment: To add templates to Ember you should do something like `Ember.TEMPLATES['templateNameGoesHere'] = Ember.Handlebars.compile('template as string should be here')`. But I'm not sure if I understand this. Do you want a template without a view, but then how do you plan to use that template? Can you say a little more on why you don't want to create a view?

Comment: My goal is simple: I need to get the HTML-Code as a string. Not a DOM-Object, nor should ember add a DOM-Node into the DOM-Tree,.. i really need pure HTML-Code as a string (generated by the template). Since this is only one line of HTML-Code, i think it is not worth to build a view. I do not need any View-Funtionalities, only the generated HTML-Code...

Comment: Look into render and renderbuffer, but I think you do need a view class

Comment: Yes, it looks like rendering ember-handlebars-templates is not possible without a view. So my next question would be: How can i get the pure HTML from a view, without adding the view to the dom? Not sure if this is a nice way to do it, but it would give me what i need in the first moment..